# Integration of Yammer with Outlook

Tags: outlook-addin, yammer, office365-apps, office365api

Can I integrate Outlook with Yammer in such a way that people in my contacts (Outlook) can be directly added in a group on Yammer ?

Or can I forward a mail directly to a user on Yammer as a message?

Is it possible to create an application that allows me to exchange data between Yammer and Outlook?

Comment: on stackoverflow (and in life), when someone tries to help you by giving his time to answer you question, you should at least have the courtesy to answer back.

Comment: Sorry sir i will take care of it :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking at seems totally possible for me. I believe the best approach would be to register your app with [Azure AD](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-how-to-register-active-directory-authentication/). Both Yammer and Outlook REST APIs can be discovered with Azure AD, see [this link](http://www.silver-it.com/node/192) for example.

So now that you know that you will target Azure AD with OAUTH flow. You have to ask yourself if you want your app to do the requests or your web server will do it (see OAUTH flow "implicit" vs "code authorization").

Comment: Thanks Benoit :-) I'm trying to use Azure AD for the same

Comment: Ok great, then. Please mark answer as accepted if it is the solution that you adopted. Bye.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30684733/yammer-rest-api-401-unauthorized-when-using-azure-ad-token-and-yammer-delegated 

I'm facing the same issue ...