# ADAL.js and Yammer authentication

Tags: javascript, azure, yammer, adal

I am having what looks very similar to this question where there is low activity now:
[Yammer REST API: 401 Unauthorized when using Azure AD token and Yammer Delegated Permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30684733/yammer-rest-api-401-unauthorized-when-using-azure-ad-token-and-yammer-delegated)

Using Adal.JS I have successfully retrieved tokens for multiple services, including https://graph.windows.net, https://graph.microsoft.net and more.

However, no matter how I try, no requests to my endpoint specified as:

```
'https://wwww.yammer.com': 'https//wwww.yammer.com'
```

will always result in a 401 Unauthorized. Did anyone run into a similar problem and managed to solve it? I can't disable SSO, from one of the answers in the above mentioned question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment, the final problem was not 401 Unauthorized but rather missing Access-Control-Allow-Origin headers, meaning the request is successful but blocked in the browser.

After contact with Microsoft it was determined that these headers are not currently added when authenticating via ADAL.js. Customers are encouraged to use the Yammer JS SDK for now.

We were also suggested trying to build a proxy request server which would forward client requests and serve the necessary headers in the response, which we are currently exploring.

Answer (score 0):

A yammer network MUST be mapped to Office 365 for ADAL integration tokens to work with Yammer API endpoints. You can tell that your network's mapping is in place if users can successfully login to Yammer using their Office 365 credentials.

I doubt this is the case for you since you're still using Yammer SSO because Yammer SSO is mutually exclusive to Office 365 sign-in for Yammer.

Yammer will be deprecating SSO on 1st Dec, 2016 so it might make some sense to start planning towards switching to Office 365 identity soon.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply.
We have enabled "Enforce Office 365 identity in Yammer", including "Block Office 365 users without Yammer licenses". Users can log in using their O365 credentials, so I think we're using the right one.

After a lot back and forth, it seems the problem are missing CORS headers (specifically Access-Control-Allow-Origin) when using ADAL, whereas they are present if I disable ADAL. Currently in contact with MS Premier support regarding this... I'll report back on any findings.

Comment: @JonasEriksson running into this now. Did you ever figure it out?

Comment: @JonasEriksson, to elaborate, I'm using an ADAL token to access graph apis without issue, but can't seem to use that token to access yammer apis. Any guidance would be much appreciated!

Comment: @MichaelArmstrong sounds like the exact same issue I had. Unfortunately, I am no longer working at that company so I don't have knowledge of what has happened since.

What eventually happened is that I created a NodeJS proxy which I queried for the images using REST. The NodeJS proxy then retrieved the images from Yammer and relayed them (with correct headers) to the JS application.

The Node app itself was easy to write, not very elegant solution. Unfortunately MS Premier Support didn't have any better suggestions. The app was hosted on Azure which was easy enough but not free.

Comment: Thanks @JonasEriksson!